# How can I programmatically start and stop an AccessibilityService?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

#### Background

I have an app that has an [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html). Android seems to keep [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html)s running all the time, but I only need mine to run *sometimes*. (Specifically, if a user opens my app and turns it off, the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) is no longer needed.)

If my [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) is running when it isn't needed, it's wasting the device's RAM and CPU, and I want to avoid doing this to my users if possible.

#### Question

How can I programmatically start and stop my [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html)?

*Note that I am **not** asking to programmatically enable or disable the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) in Android's accessibility settings; this is just about starting and stopping it when it's already enabled.*

#### What I've tried (stopping the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html))

- Disabling the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) component using the following:

  ```
  PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
      accessibilityServiceName,
      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
      0
  );
  ```

  This killed the entire application, including the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html). Also, after rebooting the phone, the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) was no longer visible in the Android accessibility settings. (It seems that the component needs to be re-enabled followed by restarting the phone in order to get it to show up again.)
- Disabling the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) component using the following:

  ```
  PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
      accessibilityServiceName,
      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
      PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
  );
  ```

  This didn't stop the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html).
- Stopping the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) using [`Context.stopService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) and [`Service.stopSelf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf(int)).
  These didn't stop the service, presumably [because the OS is bound to it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)).
- Killing the [`AccessibilityService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html)'s process using [`Process.killProcess()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess(int)). However, the service was soon after restarted and reconnected, presumably because the OS is bound to it.
- Unregistering for accessibility events using [`AccessibilityService.setServiceInfo(new AccessibilityServiceInfo())`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#setServiceInfo(android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo)). This stops the service from getting accessibility events, but the service still runs in the background.

#### Related questions

- [Can accessibility service be stopped or killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301651/can-accessibility-service-be-stopped-or-killed)

  This one is only about stopping the service. I want to be able to start the service again once it's stopped.

Comment: Can you please share a minimal project so that we can try it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from [the *Lifecycle* section of the `AccessibilityService` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html):

> The lifecycle of an accessibility service is managed exclusively by the system and follows the established service life cycle. Starting an accessibility service is triggered exclusively by the user explicitly turning the service on in device settings. After the system binds to a service, it calls [`onServiceConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#onServiceConnected()). This method can be overriden by clients that want to perform post binding setup.
>
> An accessibility service stops either when the user turns it off in device settings or when it calls [`disableSelf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#disableSelf()) (In Android 7.0 (API 24) and later).

Answer (score 2):

As stated in Sam's answer, the lifecycle of an AccessibilityService is managed exclusively by the system, so you can't kill it.

But apart resource optimization aims, if you still need to start/stop the AccessibilityService from operating in some circumstances, you can simply use the good old `SharedPreferences`.

Your Service's *onAccessibilityEvent* should be:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    if (prefs.getBoolean("isServiceEnabled", true)){
        /*
        * Your code goes here
        */
    }
}
```

When you want to "switch off/on" the service you can do it by simply writing this in some button's *onClickListener* or somewhere else according to your needs:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

prefs.edit().putBoolean("isServiceEnabled", false).apply(); // disable

prefs.edit().putBoolean("isServiceEnabled", true).apply();  // enable
```

Comment: A boolean static variable would be much more efficient.

Comment: Actually starting from API  24 it is possible: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#disableSelf()